# Scanner That Throws an Exception and Prints Out

Tags: java

So need a method that reads a txt file holding 4 integers (1,2,3,4) and throws an exception. I am think I have the scanner correct... But I want to print the values that the scanner read in my main method. I am not sure how to do that with System.out.println(). The scanner is not in the main method. 
Here is my code:

```
public static void scan()
{     
    String fileInputName  = "data.txt";
    Scanner sc = null;  

    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileInputName)));
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
        {                     
            sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    finally
    {
        if (sc != null)
            sc.close();  
    }           
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(sc.nextInt());

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Scanner question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981497/java-scanner-question)

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the scan to a variable, then print it:

Change the interface of the method

```
public List<Integer> void scan()
```

Then declare a list:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        int myInt = sc.nextInt();
        list.add(myInt);
    }
```

Then return it:

```
return list;
```

Then in your main, iterate through your list and print it out:

```
list = scan();

for (Integer i : list){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: You also might want to mention he/she should do that in the while loop.

Comment: This does not work since my scanner is not in my main method.

Comment: That while loop goes in the scanner. My goal is to not have any system.out.println() in my methods. only the main method. In the main method I want to call and prin out the integers in my txt file

Answer (score 0):

You can either assign the int go a variable and then print the variable like so:

```
System.out.println(variableInt);
```

Or you can just print it when you access it like so:

```
System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
```

Also, know that println will move a new line after it prints the thing. If you want to avoid this, simply change it to:

```
System.out.print(whatever);
```