# How to give file path as input to Java program in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java program that prompts user for input file path and name, the program will read from that file:

```
Scanner inScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
inScanner.useDelimiter("\n");
System.out.print("Enter input file path and name:");
String inFile = inScanner.next();
System.out.println("You entered: " + inFile);           
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(inFile); // FAILED HERE
```

When I ran this program within Eclipse, I got the "syntax is incorrect" error:

```
Enter input file path and name: C:\\Users\\My Work\\myFile.txt
You entered: C:\\Users\\My Work\\myFile.txt
(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)rks\myFile.txt
```

But it worked fine if I gave the same path hardcoded in the same java program and created FileInputStream from this hardcode value:

```
 private static final String inFile = "C:\\Users\\My Work\\myFile.txt";
```

So how do I give this path from input in Eclipse?  Is it because I have space in the path?  I have tried using double quotes around the input file path, or single \, or single / in the file path, it gave me the same error.  Thanks.

Comment: you may have to treat the path as a string surrounded by double quotes. perhaps try "\"C:\\Users\\My Work\\myFile.txt\"" because that how I see the command prompt treat any path that has a space in the directory name

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/530578/how-to-write-the-path-of-a-folder-with-space-in-its-name

Comment: Just tried it. Still didn't work.

Comment: you are 100% sure that you have a user called "My Work"? because that seems to be a very odd name for a user. Can you navigate to the file in a cmd/terminal using that exact path?

Comment: @ RAZ_Muh_Taz FileInputStream just take a string as argument and there is no such a string inside another double quotes

Comment: *Why* did you enter a file path with double backslashes?? A Windows file path only uses single backslashes. Double backslashes are only needed in Java code when write a `String` *literal*. Command-line inputs are not string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `inScanner.useDelimiter("\n");` causes the problem. If you delete it, the code works, regardless of using `\` or `\\` in the file path.

The method [`useDelimiter(String pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.lang.String-) uses the given `String` as a **regular expression pattern**, which behaves differently than your everyday `String` escape sequence:

> An invocation of this method of the form useDelimiter(pattern) behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(pattern)).

In Java regular expressions, both `\r` (carriage return) and `\n` (linefeed) are used as line separators. On Unix, `\n` would work, but on Windows, you need `\r\n`. So `inScanner.useDelimiter("\r\n");` would work, too. You can read more on this issue in related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981497/java-scanner-question) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445326/regex-in-java-how-to-deal-with-newline).

However, the safe variant is to just use `inScanner.nextLine();` instead of the delimiter pattern and `next();`, so you should definitely stick to that, since it is exactly made for this purpose and regular expressions are hard to master.

Comment: Thanks.  It worked.  Can you please let me know why I can't use \n as delimiter ?

Comment: Added an explanation. Just use `nextLine()`, which uses newline as a delimiter. It is far easier.